# Android memory managment for photo gallery

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I'm making same app which show a lot of images from local storage in form of ListView/GridView and I have problem with memory. Because it loads all photos in memory, although some photos aren't shown on the screen. I want to load only shown pictures and when user scroll up/down, it loads new photos and releases memory from old photos.

Can you help me with this?

I have no idea about the way how to do this.
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries that manage this issue for you. I recommend Universal Image Loader or Picasso.

Comment: Is there any way without using some library?

Comment: You can use a viewholder to manage your listview. Take a look also to RecyclerView. You can substitute your listview with it.

Comment: Can you give me some resource or some code how to implement this?

Comment: Take a look to this tutorial: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html